# Please undo all of the current [git] tag synonyms (and reject [github] synonyms)

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

### Git Synonyms

There are currently [8 tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/synonyms) for the [Git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info), along with a 9<sup>th</sup> suggested synonym. ***These synonyms should never have been created***. They all represent different, individual, and distinct commands or tools for Git...they do not all mean "Git, the distributed version control system".

The fact that these tags are all being used as synonyms for Git means that it makes it **significantly harder** to find duplicate questions involving these individual tags using the built-in search:

1. [git-remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-remote)

   `git remote` is a command used to manage your remote repo settings.
2. [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout)

   `git checkout` is a command used to manipulate the working directory of a non-bare repo.
3. [git-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-diff)

   `git diff` is a command used to diff source code.
4. [git-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bash)

   [Git Bash](http://msysgit.github.io/) is a Windows terminal that runs a Bash environment, for use with Git.
5. [git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit)

   `git commit` is a command used to commit changes.
6. [git-pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-pull)

   `git pull` is a command used to update local branches with remote changes.
7. [git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push)

   `git push` is a command used to update remote branches with local changes.
8. [git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase)

   `git rebase` is a command used to rewrite history (and make you feel like a Git god and give you massive power trips).
9. [git-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules)

   `git submodules` is a command used to manage submodule repositories within parent repos.

As I've already stated and pointed out, **none** of these synonyms should exist, because they all make it **harder to search for duplicate questions**.

### GitHub Synonyms

There is also currently an attempt to make the [GitHub Pages tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github-pages/info) a synonym for the [GitHub tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github/info).

**Please don't create and approve that synonym**. For the same reasons that I stated for the Git synonyms, [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) is a GitHub product for hosting websites, but making it a synonym for GitHub makes it **harder to search** for questions that deal specifically with GitHub Pages.

### Can a Moderator Please Undo the Synonyms?

For the existing, approved Git synonyms, can a moderator please undo them, so that the community can start tagging questions properly again, and hopefully help reduce the number of duplicate questions that get asked in the Git tag? I spend most of my Stack Overflow time in that tag, I'm about 45 upvotes away from a gold badge in it, and I see duplicate questions **All. The. Time.**

For the proposed

- [git-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules) → [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)
- [github-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-pages) → [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github)

synonyms, I encourage people to [downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/synonyms) the [synonym suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github/synonyms).

Comment: Do we *really* need a tag for *every single* git command?

Comment: @Charles if you would like to propose burnination for some, perhaps, but they at least shouldn't be synonyms either. However, as I've pointed out, command tags make it easier to find duplicates...I can simply search the most upvoted questions/answer for [tag:git-pull], for example.

Comment: @billthelizar, what was status completed? The answer?

Comment: @Braiam there was no burnination done, Bill just got rid of the synonym linkage.

Comment: @Braiam Right, just the synonym linkage was removed. A stronger case would need to be made for burnination of individual tags.

Answer (score 34):

I suggest we burn them all (except [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) and [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github)).

There are no equivalent tags for neither [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn), [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv) and there shouldn't be.

Same as we don't have tags for all java classes, all bash functions, etc.

Comment: I think git-bash should be a tag on it's own. Problems with git-bash are more likely problems with cygwin and not directly connected to git.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with burninating GitHub Pages...and quite honestly, it also makes me uncomfortable to burn the command tags too, because they do help make it easier to find relevant content and canonical answers. It looks like Bill the Lizard [already removed the synonyms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/265780/5)...so if you want to also burninate them, I suggest you start a separate discussion for that. I guess my stance on burnination right now though is *opposed*, until convinced otherwise.

Comment: @Cupcake when I have some more time, I will look into it more closely. I still think they are not in this extent useful, but I need to compare the question density for the other (D)VCS systems.

Comment: Github Pages is related to Github the same way Youtube is related to Google.

Comment: @Cupcake I added the question here removing them here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags

Comment: github and github-pages should be 2 different tags.