# Is [push] really only for Git? Or, correct tag to use for push services?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

The wiki from [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) says:

> In distributed version control, push is the action of sending local changes to a remote repository

But, contrary to this description, the [questions tagged [push]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) seem to be of a number of different varieties:

- Git push requests
- The JavaScript `Array.push` function, or equivalent, to add items to a collection
- The specific case of the above as it applies to stacks, with the obligatory [pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop)ping, bringing about [its own discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261320/what-should-we-do-with-the-pop-tag)
- Push notifications
- Who knows what else wasn't on the first couple pages

So, two questions:

1. Is the above wiki correct?

   1. If so, we need to retag the non-Git stuff.
   2. If not, what specifically should and should *not* [push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push) cover? Then the wiki needs to be edited and the other stuff *push*ed out.
2. How would one tag [Create a calendar server to publish events to subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775911/create-a-calendar-server-to-publish-events-to-subscribers) ? It seems to be about a push service, but not a [push-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push-notification) as the wiki specifically states *mobile devices*.

Comment: It is arbitrary in it's current form. It's also too specific to be worth a tag of it's own. If you wanted help with JavaScript, you wouldn't tag each method you've used by name. A possible solution would be to hyphenate the context; push-notification javascript-push php-push git-push, etc, but I'd argue they're too specific to be tags.

Comment: And there is a separate tag [tag:git-push] for GIT, which has been marked a synonym for [tag:git], which is incorrect IMO. Maybe GIT questions tagged with [push] should be retagged with [git-push]

Comment: Why is 'git-push' != 'git'?  I use tags for following topics and for restricting searches.  I can't imagine needing to narrow either one of those down to just git-push.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, I think I saw a [tag:status-completed] on the de-synonymisation of the git-blah tags. Edit: [over here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265780/please-undo-all-of-the-current-git-tag-synonyms-and-reject-github-synonyms)

Comment: Oops, looks like I missed the relevant discussion.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, Wasn't suggesting you were wrong back then just that you might be interested now. =0p

Comment: Thanks @indivisible. It is indeed good news. And your novel term "git-blah" is very funny.

Comment: There is only about 500 push questions related to git, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push+-git) search versus [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/push+git) search.

Comment: [**Dear next person who capitalizes Git as "GIT", I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a tiny "i" and a "t"**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/plurals/info).

Comment: @Cupcake, sounds like you have something against IT. What did that department ever do to you?

Comment: @Cupcake Sorry for the capitalization of Git (I have no idea what I was thinking when [I wrote that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265796/is-push-really-only-for-git-or-correct-tag-to-use-for-push-services#comment62162_265796)), will _never_ do it again

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion it's ok, you caught the GIT disease, I understand, it's very contagious, that's why you have to stamp it out before it spreads `:P`

Answer (score 3):

What about push functionality in other DVCSes? Can they use the same tag as for Git? I'd say so, so basically what we are saying here is that we need a tag for the DCVS concept of pushing.

Comment: Possibly `vcs-push`, if we want to broaden it a little further.

Comment: And making `git-push` a synonym of it? I guess most people wouldn't know what's vcs.

Comment: @Templar that would make it specific to git again, whereas the purpose is to make it general for all distributed VCSs (e.g. Mercurial). Not sure about the merit of making it general though.

Comment: @Zoltán well you can get the specific by tagging something as both `git` and `vcs-push` so I'm hesitant to needlessly specify, and how often are the questions going to be dvcs specific? I guess maybe if you are asking about a particular flag in a particular dvcs then maybe, but I'm betting often it'll be about generally pushing.