# Should we [revert] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I stumbled upon the [revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revert) tag. There are currently 355 questions tagged with this tag.

Tag description:

> Revert generally refers to operations that put a system, environment, or application into a previous state.

The tag is used with a lot of different tags and seems to be highly ambigous, and I also don't think that you can be an expert in [revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revert)-ing stuff in general.

Should we burninate this tag?

Comment: I haven't put in the work, but [does this tag actually need to be burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)?

Comment: Similar question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265796/is-push-really-only-for-git-or-correct-tag-to-use-for-push-services

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that the [tag:database] tag is also used with a lot of different tags and seems to be highly ambiguous. Shall we burninate that one next? It only has ~115k questions. I wonder if there should be some criteria other than "ambiguous" for good tags....

Comment: so to sum this "discussion" up, it should not be burninated?

Comment: I've always liked associate tags, for example [tag:html] and [tag:table] instead of [tag:html-table]. For one thing, it encourages folks to always also have the [tag:html] in there. I do realize it has been mis-used, so maybe associate tags like [tag:revert] should be allowed as long as there is a stand-alone tag such as [tag:git] listed as well?

Comment: @CodyGray You can be an expert in databases.

Comment: So why can't I be an expert in reversion? It's not like all databases are the same.

Comment: @Goose Really? I think it's a bit unrealistic for one person to be able and interested to solve ANY database problem. Wikipedia lists over [100 different databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems), but that's only *relational* database systems.

Comment: but the tag `revert` describes a lot of problems in a good way. **Q:**_how to undo this and that_ tag: `revert` what is wrong with this?

Comment: @Laurel Expert in databases and "able and interested to solve ANY database problem" is quite different. I see the point trying to be made, but I think the comparison is too different to be meaningful.