# Can we get rid of [git-something] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

There are lots of tags, one for each Git command. I think they should be removed. The questions are good enough if tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

I think they are too narrow as one can see by the low question count on each of them (compared to the 43k questions on [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)).

As the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) states, tags are there to connect experts with questions they can answer. [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) does that, while [git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit) doesn't add anything more. Also it states that new tags should only be created if they cover new ground, which these tags don't do either, so they shouldn't be there in the first place.

There are currently some tags for [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) that serve the same purpose, and I will add a meta deleting them if the current one has completed.

The question's title should state the relevant command the questioner has trouble with, not the tag on the question.

I think manually cleaning them is necessary to ensure they are all tagged with Git and have their relevant command in the title.

Here's a list of all tags that I could find that I think applies.
[git-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add), [git-alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-alias), [git-am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-am), [git-annex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-annex), [git-apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-apply), [git-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-archive), [git-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bare), [git-bisect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bisect), [git-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch), [git-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bundle), [git-cherry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cherry), [git-cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cherry-pick), [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout), [git-clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-clean), [git-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-clone), [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands), [git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit), [git-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-config), [git-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-core), [git-credential-winstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-credential-winstore), [git-cvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cvs), [git-daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-daemon), [git-describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-describe), [git-detached-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-detached-head), [git-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-diff), [git-difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-difftool), [git-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-extensions), [git-fastimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fastimport), [git-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fetch), [git-filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter-branch), [git-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-flow), [git-fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fork), [git-fsck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fsck), [git-ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-ftp), [git-gc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-gc), [git-hg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-hg), [git-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-index), [gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore), [git-interactive-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-interactive-rebase), [git-internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-internals), [git-media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-media), [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge), [git-new-workdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-new-workdir), [git-notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-notes), [git-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-patch), [git-post-receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-post-receive), [git-pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-pull), [git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push), [git-p4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-p4), [git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase), [git-reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reflog), [git-remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-remote), [git-rerere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rerere), [git-reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reset), [git-revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-revert), [git-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-review), [git-rev-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rev-list), [git-rewrite-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rewrite-history), [git-rm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rm), [git-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-shell), [git-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-show), [git-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-slave), [git-squash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-squash), [git-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stage), [git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash), [git-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-status), [git-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules), [git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subtree), [git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-svn), [git-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tag), [git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tf), [git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tfs), [git-track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-track), [git-update-server-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-update-server-info), [git-verify-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-verify-pack), [git-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-workflow)

I've left out the ones where I felt that they are not part of this problem (without caring if they should be removed for other reasons).

For those who oppose the elimination, how about synonyming them to [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands), [git-interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-interoperability) (for [git-cvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cvs), [git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-svn)...) and other abstractions to have one tag to hold them all?

This question already had some discussion in [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265780/please-undo-all-of-the-current-git-tag-synonyms-and-reject-github-synonyms?lq=1).

Comment: Cupcake attack in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: [*One tag to rule them all, One tag to find them; One tag to bring them all, and in the darkness **close** them*](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Ring-inscription). I thing a [tag:git-commands] tag is a *terrible* idea, by the way. You might as well just stick with [tag:git], if you're going to go that route.

Comment: @Cupcake I won't oppose just going with git :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with these tags?  Why is "too narrow" a problem?  If tags are too narrow, they'll never get used, and nobody will ever see them.  I think meaningless tags are a far worse problem.

Comment: So, as I've stated elsewhere, command tags allow me to quickly find highly upvoted questions about particular commands, so that I can use them to close duplicates. I suppose I could still use advanced search to dig up canonicals...I don't know. It's just kind of nice being able to just click a single tag, instead of making a complicated search query that might miss something.

Comment: Searching for duplicates can be a very time-consuming process, sometimes. Anything that makes that process more efficient is great, and commands tags are efficient.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are against the advises from the help center for tags. I've edited a paragraph into the question for this.

Comment: OK, but all the Help Center says in that regard is that tags should specify "well-defined categories."  It says nothing about tags being too narrow, and the current community gestalt is for tags to be *more specific,* not less.

Comment: Please tell me you used programming to generate the Markdown for all of those tag names instead of writing `[tag:tagName]` over and over again...

Comment: @RobertHarvey but we really need a tag for each command of git? svn? mg? I mean, ok, we want more specific tags, but do they add so much value to any question tagged as such?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If we go that way with other tools,  functions, types and so on too, shall we revisit hierarchical tags then?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that most people able to answer git questions would be able to answer git-checkout questions. If you're good with git, you'll probably know your way around most of these functions, thus the tags are not going to help any "answerers". There's no reason for tags to be specific if it doesn't serve a purpose. Of course making duplicate searches easier is a purpose.

Comment: I agree that the tags that cover `git` internals should be covered by the `git` tag. Some of those tags aren't specific to `git`, however likely too narrow, such as `git-workflow`. That should probably remain but become more generalized.

Comment: @AstroCB vi. `:%s/, /], [tag:/g`

Comment: @SteveBuzonas Would you add an answer stating which tags should be merged and which not and why?

Comment: They are *contextual* tags.  A questioner will always use [git] first and then emphasize what part of git he's having a problem with by adding, say, [git-cherry].  It avoids adding a whole bunch of meaningless tags, like [cherry].  Because, you know, we're programmers, not birds :)  This is not a real problem of course.

Comment: Please tag this post with git-meta.

Comment: Please don't git-rid-of-them, yes some tags end up being narrow, but as long as it helps someone find a question on that specific tag, it's doing its job. Covnersely, putting everything under the big git umbrella will not help people find questions.

Comment: It is a shame that we can't force the "git" tag to always be used when one of these "sub tags" are used.

Comment: Those proposed synonyms are kinda useless. They don't help someone who is searching for answers about a specific command or tool or someone who wants to filter because they have specific expertise. And what happens a few years down the road when there's 5000 [git-interoperability] questions and people can't find stuff and want to filter? Do we then have to go back a retag them all into the proper tools: [git-svn], [git-cvs], [git-tf], etc. ?

Comment: @Robert: "What exactly is the problem with these tags?" - I think the issue is a question will be tagged with `git-add`, bit not `git`. Then the expert who trolls `git` will miss the question. I don't know if it happens often; but if it can happen, I would expect it to happen.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think the Git command tags should remain. We should **not** get rid of them.

### Advantages of individual tags

- **For Gold Badge experts:** [As Cupcake said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags#comment64486_266221), individual tags make it easier to find duplicates.
- **For Regular Users:** Specific tags make it easier to find relevant questions when one is looking for details regarding any particular command.
- **For Askers:** If these tags are removed, most askers will be left with only one tag option "git". Unable to find relevant meaningful tags, users will tend to use incorrect tags such as "command" and "repository". Removing specific tags will encourage incorrect tagging.

[image]

- **For Answerers:** [As megawac said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags/266254#comment65005_266254), answerers watch specific command tags because they find some specific git functions get interesting questions. An umbrella "git" tag is too broad.
- The individual wikis will be lost if the tags are burninated/merged.

### Are they eligible for Tag Synonyms?

> [When should I propose a tag synonym?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with **the wrong or incorrect tag** -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to avoid manually editing the tags on every post by making the retagging automatic for **common tag mistakes**.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

**No.** In the case of Git, the questions have been tagged with the relevant command-tags.
Since "common tag mistakes" are not widespread in Git command tags, this is not a good case for tag synonyms.

### Are they eligible for tag removal (burnination)?

[This FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/2982225) says:

> How do you determine when a tag is bad?
>
> **When a tag implies no clearly defined meaning** (this could either be in
> its name, or in its tag wiki). Something like "a generic term", as is
> the case with merge, is usually a bad sign. This could perhaps be
> considered synonymous to a tag having vastly differing possible
> meanings - a MERGE keyword in SQL and a merge in SVN are both
> generically involve 'merging', but you can't list too many
> similarities between the two.
>
> **When a tag has a clearly defined meaning, but is still misused often**.
> In this case it might be more appropriate to have the questions
> containing this tag be retagged to contain tags less susceptible to
> misuse. Let's say the merge tag's wiki were to have indicated that it
> related to merging on SVN, but then a lot of questions related to the
> SQL MERGE keyword also used this tag (which already has a sql-merge
> tag). Then it might have been appropriate to retag merge to svn-merge.

<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>

**No.** The Git tags in the discussion do not meet the above stated criteria.

- *"When a tag implies no clearly defined meaning"*
  Most Git tags have individual tag wikis describing the respective commands. They are clearly defined.
- *"When a tag has a clearly defined meaning, but is still misused often"*
  The questions have been tagged with the relevant command-tags. Since "common tag mistakes" are not widespread in Git command tags. (Please mention if cases of common misuse of these Git tags are found.)

### Now let's see the numbers

Are these tags relevant? Do they have tag wikis? Are they really used in any significant number of questions?

To correctly assess their importance, popularity and impact of burnination, take a look at the numbers below:

[.git-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.git-folder) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 6
[.git-info-grafts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.git-info-grafts) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 5
[git-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 219
[git-alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-alias) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 64
[git-am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-am) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 23
[git-annex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-annex) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 36
[git-apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-apply) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 14
[git-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-archive) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 31
[git-assume-unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-assume-unchanged) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 6
[git-bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bare) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 134
[git-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bash) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1119
[git-bisect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bisect) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 58
[git-bisect-skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bisect-skip) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 2
[git-blame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-blame) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 41
[git-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1937
[git-branch-sculpting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-branch-sculpting) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 12
[git-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bundle) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 14
[git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 456
[git-cherry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cherry) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 10
[git-cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cherry-pick) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 183
[git-clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-clean) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 32
[git-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-clone) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 681
[git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 60
[git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 950
[git-completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-completion) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 5
[git-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-config) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 310
[git-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-conflict-resolution) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 108
[git-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-core) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 0
[git-credential-winstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-credential-winstore) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-cvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-cvs) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 25
[git-daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-daemon) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 29
[git-dangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-dangling) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 10
[git-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-deploy) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 2
[git-describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-describe) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 17
[git-detached-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-detached-head) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 38
[git-diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-diff) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 586
[git-diff-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-diff-tree) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 11
[git-difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-difftool) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 42
[git-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-extensions) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 277
[git-fast-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fast-import) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 23
[git-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fetch) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 181
[git-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 14
[git-filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter-branch) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 302
[git-fixup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fixup) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 2
[git-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-flow) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 604
[git-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-for-windows) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 13
[git-fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fork) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 215
[git-fsck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fsck) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 16
[git-ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-ftp) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 28
[git-gc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-gc) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 34
[git-grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-grep) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-gui) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 168
[git-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-hash) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-history-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-history-graph) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 20
[git-http-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-http-backend) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 8
[git-http-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-http-protocol) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 1
[git-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-index) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 56
[git-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-init) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 25
[git-interactive-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-interactive-rebase) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 29
[git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-lfs) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 179
[git-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-log) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 516
[git-ls-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-ls-files) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 13
[git-ls-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-ls-tree) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 3
[git-media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-media) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 2
[git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1713
[git-mv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-mv) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 12
[git-new-workdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-new-workdir) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 3
[git-non-bare-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-non-bare-repository) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-notes) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 21
[git-p4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-p4) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 95
[git-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-patch) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 63
[git-plumbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-plumbing) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 25
[git-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-portable) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 1
[git-post-receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-post-receive) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 184
[git-pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-pull) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 706
[git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 873
[git-push-force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-push-force) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 1
[git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1022
[git-reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reflog) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 42
[git-refspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-refspec) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-remote) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 540
[git-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-repo) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 55
[git-rerere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rerere) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 28
[git-reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-reset) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 262
[git-rev-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rev-list) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 27
[git-revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-revert) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 251
[git-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-review) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 32
[git-revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-revision) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 7
[git-rewrite-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rewrite-history) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 192
[git-rm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rm) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 78
[git-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-shell) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 51
[git-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-show) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 42
[git-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-sign) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 7
[git-skip-worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-skip-worktree) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 5
[git-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-slave) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 9
[git-sparse-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-sparse-checkout) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 4
[git-squash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-squash) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 72
[git-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stage) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 51
[git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 444
[git-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-status) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 122
[git-submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1672
[git-subrepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subrepo) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 10
[git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-subtree) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 362
[git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-svn) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1682
[git-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tag) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 289
[git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tf) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 71
[git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tfs) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 142
[git-tower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tower) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 87
[git-track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-track) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 16
[git-untracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-untracked) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 14
[git-update-server-info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-update-server-info) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 1
[git-verify-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-verify-pack) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 4
[git-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-workflow) • Tag Wiki ✓ • Tagged questions : 116
[git-worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-worktree) • Tag Wiki ✗ • Tagged questions : 19

Comment: I don't think that "it makes it easier to find duplicates" is a good enough reason to keep all of these tags around.  Are there really experts in git-track or git-squash?

Comment: If only tags help finding duplicates effectively, there is some serious problem these days with Google search...

Comment: @cimmanon, I agree on that point, but he listed other reasons to keep them besides that one. Also, there doesn't necessarily need to be experts in tags, tags are for finding/organizing things, not defining communities of experts

Comment: @FinalContest Google doesn't take question score into account.

Comment: @Cupcake: It does. More popular threads are put ahead. If not, google must be broken. ^^

Comment: What if Git experts could add "git-*" to the tags they're following and it would follow all of the git tags?

Comment: @gitsitgo Ahem..she listed..

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Sorry, I ran substr(1) on the word 'she' at the wrong time =/

Comment: If git-rebase is not a frequently used command, I must be doing git wrong.

Comment: @Patrick when in doubt, rebase is *always* the answer.

Comment: I watch `git-tree-filter` and some other narrow topics because I find some specific git functions get interesting questions

Comment: Your example for askers without the `git-merge` tag is broken... the `repository` tag is useless if you already have the `git` tag on the question. Also I don't see much value in adding the `command` tag. In other words I'd simply tag the question `git` + `merge`, which looks even better than `git` + `git-merge`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is broken @Bakuriu. In absence of correct tags, users may tend to use incorrect tags. The example is meant to illustrate "incorrect tagging" behaviour. _"Removing specific tags will encourage incorrect tagging."_

Comment: At present, [these kind of incorrect tagging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+repository) [is minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+command+repository). My hypothetical example was based on these. @Bakuriu

Comment: @FinalContest Specific questions rank high in Google results due to PageRank, which is based on links and other statistics.  It's just coincidental that highly-upvoted questions/answers are usually near the top of results, and many times a specific "[some tag] some keywords" search directly on SO has given me much better results

Comment: Is there really a difference between [tag:git-cherry] and [tag:git-cherry-pick] ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, then can be merged

Comment: I'm in favor of getting rid of `git-cvs`, `git-svn`, `git-internals`, and `git-difftool`, but I think we should keep the rest.

Answer (score 10):

Additional reasons to keep these specific Git command tags:

### Filtering out tags that I don't want to see

I'm going to be honest: I don't use [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). At all. I have very little experience with them, and I don't find them to be particularly interesting.

So, naturally, I'm not really interested in answering questions tagged with `[git-submodules]`, of which there are currently [750 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules?sort=newest).

So while I *do* want to have `[git]` questions show up and be highlighted in my question feeds, I'd rather not see the questions that are also tagged with `[git-submodules]` too. The specific command tags allow me to set up this kind of filtering.

### Filtering questions in the close review queue

Closing duplicates can be an *extremely* time-consuming process, even with a [gold-badge dupe hammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers) for Git:

[image: Git Mjolnir]

It could be beneficial for someone like me to focus on reviewing duplicates of *specific* commands, instead of just filtering down to the Git tag in general, because if I find a duplicate question involving `git push`, I have a higher chance of closing other `git push` questions as duplicates more efficiently, thus saving me time and effort.

*Side note:* I've found that I can close more questions faster if I just [filter down to **off-topic** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=offtopic), because these will often be recommendation questions, which take very little effort to review. Closing duplicates takes considerably more reviewing effort, so that's why every little bit to make the process more efficient helps.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I think it looks like [you handled everything pretty well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266254/456814) without me `;)`

Comment: L.O.L...was just holding the fort till you come by. Finally, the [much awaited Cupcake attack](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags/266745?noredirect=1#comment64477_266221) `:-P`

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion oh, I assure you, I had something else in mind, but the Creative Commons license and US copyright law prevent me from using it... *for now* ...