# Burn individual CSS unit tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

I have noticed there is a [pt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pt), [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units), and [em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em)<sup>1</sup> tags. To me, having individual ones like this is overly detailed for a programming website like SO.

We already have an incredibly generic [units-of-measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/units-of-measurement) tag, but should we create a [css-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-units) tag and burn the individual tags? It would allow for more units to be added to CSS in the future without the need for more tags.

What do you think?

<sub>1. The [em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em) is also stands for expectation-maximization and is validly used there and thus shouldn't be burned completely.</sub>

Comment: Some em tags are also being used for the HTML `<em>` element.

Comment: What is your rationale for consolidating such tags to a css-units tag?

Comment: em and pt are units in typesetting, it's conceivable they might crop up on (La)TeX questions, too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The rational behind it was that people interested in answering questions specifically dealing with font usage could favorite the tag, but I suppose following the CSS and fonts tags would suffice

Comment: How would you defend against that the tags makes it easier to divide the scopes of CSS, makes searching by tags more specific and therefore more practical duplicate post hunting, and also preventing misuse with other ambiguous tags from lack of specific ones? Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags/266254#266254

Comment: @Unihedro Using that rational we should have a whole lot more detailed tags... The reason behind deleting them is because the ones listed are ultimately not needed because other tags can be used to convey the same meaning

Comment: I support the burnination, but I'm not sure about generalizing them as [tag:css-units]. They are too common and there are usages outside of CSS. Android also has a property called "ems", which is related to [em]. OT: the tag [em] should be at least disambiguated. Currently the tag wiki only describes em as typography, but no "expectation-maximization" at all. Perhaps creating a tag for it is more appropriate.

Comment: @AndrewT. Weird. The `em` tag includes expectation-maximization in the tag excerpt but not the full one

Comment: @ZachSaucier Some of these may be significant to the question, since using `em` vs `px` can introduce radically different behavior (and may trigger browser bugs). Whether those should be tags or mentioned somewhere in the question, I'm not sure.

Comment: em is actually the width of the letter m. not sure where you get expectation maximization. but i like it.

Comment: Honestly, these units are a fundamental part of the CSS language itself and should not need a tag of their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't feel that a generalized tag for units in CSS is necessary or useful at all. The concept of units is a fundamental part of the CSS language and is adequately covered by the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag. Any pertinent details are just that — details — and  should therefore be highlighted in the prose instead.

Something like [css-calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-calc) is different because it's an entire feature in its own right. I'm not sure about [viewport-units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewport-units) however — it's exactly what it says on the tin, but at the same time it refers to a *category* of units that is quite unique in itself as well. Also, like [css-calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-calc), it's new to CSS3.

The two-letter tag [em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em) is too ambiguous to be useful; if it stands for something else that warrants its own tag, that tag should have a different name.

Answer (score 17):

[em](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/em) is NOT validly used for expectation maximization.

I've significant training in systems engineering (optimization) and I wouldn't associate EM to mean that out of context, so it's pretty much a given that at least 99.9% of users won't either.  The term needs to be spelled out, if it even deserves its own tag and doesn't just fall under a broader tag such as "optimization" or "stochastic optimization".

Comment: Uhhhhh what? "em is a unit of measurement in the context of typography. It can also stand for expectation-maximization in the context of statistics." It can't be both....

Comment: Even though I don't have any experience in statistic, I agree with this answer. Then perhaps we can start to clean-up EM questions that are tagged with [tag:em] first (which closely-related to [tag:opencv]).

Comment: I just came across a [tag:em] post in LQRQ, which brought me to this post. Looks like the tag still hasn't been disambiguated or cleaned up, and people are continuing to use it for both the CSS unit and expectation maximization.. anyone for cleanup?