# A similar tag to [opengi] already exists

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28855144/1).

The OP was asking about [OpenGI](http://opengi.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html), a similarly named C library, but tagged it [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl).

I'm now aware that OpenGI actually integrates with OpenGL, so that tag is still appropriate, but might still need an OpenGI one.

There already exists a tag [opengis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengis) (not related), which SO saw as a duplicate of [opengi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengi) and explicitly prompted me to ask this...

Should a tag be created for [opengi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengi)?

More generally, and ignoring the topic of tags with similar spelling, what defines the threshold for less well known names to become tags?

Comment: It is unrelated to `OpenGIS`, so the prompting reason was incorrect.  `OpenGI`, if there is sufficient volume, is a distinct topic from what I can tell.

Comment: Regarding the more general question about what gets to be a tag, [the FAQ entry](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/2359271) only says that you should create tags when you see a "clear need" for them to exist. [This discussion about the many git command tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266221/2359271) is very relevant to how the meta community audits the general community's perception of "clear need."

Comment: The prompting reason was correct; the name [opengi] shares sufficient overlap, letter-wise, with the existing [opengis] tag, that the system (which obviously has no context as to what the letters "opengi" or "opengis" actually mean) rightfully cautioned against the creation of the tag.

Comment: it's also a warning, lazy users will start typing and then tab+enter autocomplete not realizing they picked the wrong tag.  Is there a way we could expand `OpenGI` that would be clear as to what was meant without being too long?