# Should we [annotate] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

[annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotate) has 155 questions, associated with a number of languages.

Within [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), some of them are to do with a specific gem called "annotate". I think these should be called [annotate-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotate-gem).

Maybe the git questions should get a tag called [git-annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-annotate), as per the consensus at [Can we get rid of [git-something] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags) , but some may disagree.

I don't know what should happen to the rest, though.