# Stop executing [git-commands]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) tag doesn't seem to quite fit the four requirements for deletion:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **yes it applies, but ambiguously**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **yes, I believe [git] is on topic**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **no, I don't think so**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **no it's ambiguous, but it could just be [git]**

personally I don't see [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) adding anything that [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) doesn't already give you

from its wiki:

> This is a generalized tag for git commands such as git diff, git merge, git commit etc.

there are 128 questions tagged [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands), of those 122 are tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) (6 are missing [git])

I don't think a synonym is quite appropriate here.  My proposal is to retag those 6 missing [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) and remove [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands)

Comment: The [tag:git-commands] tag appears to have been burned before, although I cannot find a meta discussion for it. A related, but more general, [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags) discusses all of the then-current "git" related tags.

Comment: *"personally I don't see git-commands adding anything that git doesn't already give you"* - Well, you could argue that it makes a distinction between editing the .gitconfig file or installing git and such, and things that actually requires git commands. But I agree. It does not add much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> personally I don't see [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) adding anything that [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) doesn't already give you

Agreed; the [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) tag was a useless, pseudo-synonym of [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). It is now a *real* synonym of [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). All questions that were previously tagged [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) have been merged into the questions tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

Here are those 6 questions you mentioned that originally had the [git-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commands) tag *without* the [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag:

- [How do i write "cp git ls-files --modified" in a batch file. This command works fine in Git bash but when i invoke from batch file it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100089/how-do-i-write-cp-git-ls-files-modified-in-a-batch-file-this-command-works)
- [Git commands for getting the latest changes into local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141107/git-commands-for-getting-the-latest-changes-into-local)
- [When using mysygit (GitGui), is there a log of the git bash commands executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820694/when-using-mysygit-gitgui-is-there-a-log-of-the-git-bash-commands-executed)
- [Why mkdir cannot be called in tcl script envoked by git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554726/why-mkdir-cannot-be-called-in-tcl-script-envoked-by-git)
- [Egit with Eclipse for Java sending git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675315/egit-with-eclipse-for-java-sending-git-commands)
- [How to script git commands in a Windows bat script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660025/how-to-script-git-commands-in-a-windows-bat-script)

All clearly *needed* the [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag, and none benefitted in any way from a unique tag.