# How to tag going forward now that Git checkout has been split into switch & restore

Tags: discussion, tags

The Git [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) command was split into two commands in the [2.23 release](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt) in August 2019: [`restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) & [`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).

The existing `checkout` command [isn't going anywhere any time soon](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d787d311dbd7a4104a9dde23b90ae24528a15cf9):

> The good
> old "git checkout" command is still here and will be until all (or most
> of users) are sick of it.

The new commands are currently marked as "experimental" ([`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), [`restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)):

> THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.

Currently, Stack Overflow has the pre-existing tag for `git checkout`: [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout) with 1,007 questions; and one for the new `git switch` functionality: [git-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-switch) with 4 questions.  There does not yet exist a `get restore` tag ([git-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-restore)).

What's the proper thing to do going forward with regard to tagging Git questions related to switching branches or restoring working tree files?  Do we tag all of them with [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout) plus whichever one of [git-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-switch) or [git-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-restore) is applicable depending on whether they're switching or restoring?  Do we use whichever tag corresponds to the command(s) actually used by the OP?  Do we only use [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout) or only use [git-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-switch) & [git-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-restore)?

Note: Another, more nuclear option was proposed and discussed over seven years ago: get rid of all the Git subtags and only use [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) ([Can we get rid of [git-something] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266221/1108305)).

Comment: Do we really need a tag for each function? Isn't the [tag:git] tag enough?

Comment: @BDL That was proposed and discussed seven years ago: [Can we get rid of \[git-something\] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266221/1108305)

Comment: I would have thought that if someone is specifically asking a question about `git checkout` then they should use the [tag:git-checkout] tag; and if anyone asks a question about `git switch` then they should use the [tag:git-switch] tag. If the question doesn't mention either of those, use neither tag. Isn't that how tags work?

Answer (score 9):

#### I don't think we need to force this to go one way or another

There are already great, appropriately-tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) resources on Stack Overflow regarding `git checkout` and beyond, which occurred without significant orchestration... I suspect this will sort itself out over time too.

[git-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-switch) was created organically by the community, and [git-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-restore) is likely to follow– but don't force its creation before then.

New questions will get tagged appropriately as they come. Questions concerning the new commands can be tagged under their respective like-named tags, *if* the questions revolve specifically around those commands (not just questions that happen to mention or use them).

The new tags should stay separate from [git-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-checkout), since these are separate commands. *Existing* questions shouldn't be retagged with these new tags, because they aren't about the new commands.

There will be some who don't think we need more *`git-$command`* tags, but I'd refer them to the [well-put answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266221/1108305) (which you supplied the link for above) arguing for the contrary. Tags are useful when they describe a specific topic that benefits both question askers and answerers– the new tags in this case appear to serve that end just fine.